# How can I update addressed id they look some what the same

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to try to fix addressed in the address column on a database?

so if I have 2 records
123 Main RD
123 Main Road

I want to make they both the same it does not matter which one to select as long as they are the same?

Is there a possible way to do this in MySQL?

the table looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE address (
id int(11),
address1 varchar(255),
account_id int(11)
);

id -> address1 ->   account_id
10 -> 123 Main RD          -> 65
20 -> 123 Main ROAD        -> 65
25 -> 8751 West 1st Street -> 65
27 -> 4521 11th Ave        -> 65
```

so I want to compare the addresses that share the same account_id and not all of them
so If I have 10 records with the same account_id then I only want to compare the 10 addresses against each other and not all the database.

Comment: We need to see your complete table structure, please.

Comment: @user1477388 please see my post as I just included that + some extra notes

Comment: **1.** Where is the second address field which you want to compare to?  **2.** You shouldn't use `int` as a column name since it's a reserved word.

Comment: There are many different approaches to this common problem. You could use REPLACE AND LCASE to normalise words that are likely to be abbreviated in this way but it will only catch some basic cases. How many address records do you need to process?

Comment: @user1477388 that was a type i corrected it. I am trying to compare it to the same column. There is only 1 column

Comment: @nnichols can you please explain how can I use user REPLACE AND LCASE to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a wild guess but if all rows with the same `account_id` should have the same address you can do following

```
UPDATE address a JOIN
(
  SELECT *
    FROM address
   WHERE account_id = 65
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 1
) q ON a.account_id = q.account_id
   SET a.address1 = q.address1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2680d/1)**

Comment: great idea. damn missed 4 characters now its longer.

Comment: But I don't know the account id. I have more that 50k addressed and I need to run a generic query that will find a update all possible addresses to be the same

Comment: But that will set all addresses for each account to the first address found for each account. I don't think that is what the OP is after. I am assuming there can be multiple disparate addresses per account?

Comment: @Mike If you are OK with the basic idea then I can help you with a query that will do that for whole table automatically

Comment: nnicholas correct an address can have mutiple addresses and they may not be the same. shipping address/mailing addresss so I only want to update the addresses that look the same

Comment: @peterm the only issue with that is what is the some accounts have completelty different addresses those I don't want to change. I only want to change the once that look a like.

Comment: @Mike OK. You should've put all these essential information in your question in the first place not letting us squeezing it from you drop by drop

Comment: i did not think of that at the beginning so I have added it on my question

Answer (score 0):

This is only a simple example as a starting point -

```
SELECT
    account_id,
    REPLACE(LCASE(address1), ' rd', ' road') AS address,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM address
GROUP BY account_id, address
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: But this will replace only rd to a Road in the provided example. it could be a street st or st. or it can be suite # ..... I mean there could be many different option I don't want to have to guess all the possibilities.

Comment: @Mike then make a list with all possible abbreviation and read from it with a JOIN, and they aren't few.

Comment: Some addressed has suite number and some don't. Can we use LIKE operation some how?

Comment: @Mike see peterm answer I think that would be easier for u